# Automatic Notification of New or Changed Files in a Folder or Share

Tags: linux, windows, files, directory

I'm looking for some Open Source [free] or relatively inexpensive solution for monitoring specific folders on a file system and 'Windows' network with several shares. When a file is added or changed, I would like to be able to notify myself and/or others that there is a new file, or changes to the current files. We have a SBS 2003 Server with a couple of shares, in a small non-profit office.

I would prefer:

- Runs on Server Side (we have both Windows and Linux servers)
- Notification on different time scales - hourly/daily/weekly
- Notification sent via e-mail to different addresses

It would be entirely possible to 'roll my own' using bash/php/program of choice but I am curious as to any current solutions to avoid re-inventing the wheel. Also would love to hear anyone using a current system or how they have implemented this idea in their office.

Also most office workers are non-computer literate so git or other version control system isn't an option at this point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your linux server you can use [inotify-tools](http://inotify-tools.sourceforge.net/) based on [inotify](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify).
For your windows server I haven't a solution.

Comment: +1 for inotify for Linux systems. Also check out http://iwatch.sourceforge.net/ which is a perl script that uses inotify.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted an Open Source tool, I'd recommend [OSSEC](http://www.ossec.net) (works on both Windows and Linux), which also offers commercial support if required.

A commercial option is [Verisys](http://www.ionx.co.uk). It's easy to use and a lot cheaper than Tripwire (from your question I would say that Tripwire would be way too expensive, and bloated for your requirements).

Answer (score 0):

You could use WMI events to make this happen (note: a common mistake is to use `__InstanceModificationEvent` rather than `("SELECT * FROM __InstanceOperationEvent)`  but I'd suggest implementing windows sharepoint server. SBS 2003 however has some unique issues if you want to upgrade to the latest version rather than using the version included.  See  [WSS v3.0 Installation on SBS 2003](http://blogs.technet.com/sbs/archive/2006/11/30/wss-v3-0-installation-on-sbs-2003.aspx) and [Installing Windows SharePoint Services 3.0 on a Server Running Windows Small Business Server 2003](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=0daafc81-efff-4f5b-a28a-8265f1e99f5b&displaylang=en)

With sharepoint you get all notifications you or your users could want and a whole lot more.

Comment: +1 for SharePoint; seems to meet the requirement better.

Answer (score 0):

The following tools are worth considering

- Osiris -http://osiris.shmoo.com/
- samhain - http://la-samhna.de/samhain/index.html

If you are open to commercial software, then you can have a look at Tripwire enterprise. The OSS version AFAIK can not be run on Windows.

Tripwire enterprise - http://www.tripwire.com/products/enterprise/index.cfm